# update code of invoice id assigned in different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using different tables using a union to reove duplicates and provide me with results

now i want to update the results of that with update query how can i doo it

here is my query

```
select zohoinvoice_id as invoice_id,status,'' as link from zoho_details where active = 0
            union
            select invoice_id,status,'' as link from latest_invoices where active = 0
            union
            select invoice_id,status,'' as link from search_invoices where active = 0
            union
            select zohoinvoice_id as invoice_id,status,'gen' as link from zoho_details where active = 1 AND status = 'Void'
```

i want to update that if `update table set gen = '' where invoice_id in (the query above which is joining with different tables`

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I would separate the conditions into multiple `where` expressions:

```
update table t
    set gen = ''
    where t.invoice_id in (select zohoinvoice_id from zoho_details where active = 0) or
          t.invoice_id in (select invoice_id from latest_invoices where active = 0) or
          t.invoice_id in (select invoice_id from search_invoices where active = 0) or
          t.invoice_id in (select zohoinvoice_id from zoho_details where active = 1 AND status = 'Void');
```

Multiple expressions makes it easier for the optimizer to optimize the query.  I should also note that the first and fourth conditions could be combined into a single subquery.

Comment: but update which table, because invoiceid can be in any one of it

Comment: I thought you had the invoice id in another table that you wanted updated.  You should edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: i think the question is clear as to what i need to ask, i do not see any problem in database table where i a asking something irrelevant